# Did gravity exist before the Big Bang?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, astrophysics, universe, big-bang

Gravity is one of the biggest mysteries. It is the weakest of the 4 fundamental forces but we have no clue how it works. Einstein never was able to figure it out in his lifetime. There is evidence that gravity affects time, another very poorly understood phenomenon. Now the universe was once in a tiny singularity point before the Big Bang and then rapidly expanded. Something held the universe together in that singularity point. Was it gravity? Does gravity predate the universe?

Comment: Although a lot of questions are unsolved, as always, saying that 'Einstein never was able to figure it out in his lifetime.' is a hard thing to say about the person that introduced general relativity. :-) Also, *cosmic inflation*, a period of exponential cosmic expansion in the beginning of the universe got rid of the singularity at the 'Big Bang'.

Comment: I’m not knocking Einstein LOL. I’m just pointing out how difficult gravity is that not even a once in a lifetime genius like him couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: I would say yes, why not? If not, it would mean we have an energy singularity - ... and this comes close to God's light. It would also be the same asking, "does electromagnetic force exist before Big Bang?".

Comment: My whole thing is that gravity keeps things binded. The initial singularity was held together by something. It might’ve been gravity. Electromagnetism has no relevance to that.

Comment: -1. I disagree with essentially every single sentence of your question. And the very question is as meaningful as asking "what is North of the North Pole".

Comment: I think you are being far too hasty. I am asking what binded what would later be called the universe in a singularity point. Gravity seems to be the only known force that operates in that way. Also gravity DOES have an effect on time as there is gravitational time dilation.

Answer (score -4):

This is how I like to look at the situation before the big bang: At the quantum level everything is just a wave.  A quark is a wave in the quark field, a gluon is a wave in the gluon field, an electron is just a wave in the electromagnetic field.  Before the big bang, try not to think of ALL the stuff in our current universe as being held together by gravity.  Rather, just think of a wave and we don't know what that wave was made of. What happened during the big bang is that the wave fluttered, and all the other waves in our current universe were emitted.  As a simplistic way to visualize this, imagine a calm pond.  You drop in one big rock and that creates a hole bunch of large and small waves and ripples that bounce around and interact with each other.  Some particles (spin 1/2 particles like quarks or electrons) are faced with the Pauli Exclusion Principle and so cannot exist in the same place and time.  Other particles, (spin 1 particles like gluons) can exist in the same place and time.  So there is no reason why an infinite number could not have existed in the singularity that was before the big bang.  This might be the situation at the centre of a black hole.

So it was not necessary for gravity to exist before the big bang.  Most models say that gravity arose in the first tiny fraction of a second after the big bang, at the same time that quarks and gluons formed (before electrons).

You mentioned the relationship between gravity and time.  I would say that gravity does not affect time; rather that gravity is time dilation (or spacetime dilation if you will).  One cannot exist without the other because they are the same thing.

Finally, you mentioned that gravity is the weakest of the four forces.  Although this is widely thought, I would disagree.  I have yet to see the magnet powerful enough to actually stop time.   Gravity is only the weakest force because we have not yet been able to organize it in the way that we organize electron spin in a magnet.

And there are a number of theories of gravity out there. Perhaps one will turn out to be correct.

Comment: This sounds more like a nice narration than a science-based answer... Also, "At the quantum level everything is just a wave." is a deeply incorrect statement. You seem to be aware of fields, and yet there's some confusion between one-mass shell particles on one hand and wave-particle duality on the other...

Comment: @Miyase I am anxious to read your answer to the original question.

Comment: My providing an answer of my own or not is unrelated to the fact that your answer isn't scientific. Don't misunderstand me, it's perfectly fine to wish for things, or to imagine what could be beyond the field of our current understanding. But in in the context of Stack Exchange, in the Physics site, answers can be expected to be a bit more substantiated. Or at least start with a clear disclaimer regarding its nature.

Comment: @Miyase you would have to read my complete theory of time dilation gravity and dark matter to understand where I'm coming from. Not very scientific, as you would put it, but still the only complete theory that I've seen so far.
 https://vixra.org/abs/2202.0156